# How do we generate the samples of hidden root nodes in the Bayes network (Sigmoid Belief Networks) of a generative model

Tags: bayesian-network, generative-models

Following is a `Sigmoid Belief Networks` where we can only observe the `bottom observable layer` $v.$ Usually we use `Wake-Sleep` to trainning the bottom-to-up `Recognition Weight` $r_{ji}$ and up-to-bottom `Generative Weight` $w_{ij}.$ The conditional probability of all the nodes except for the top layer root nodes $(h^{(2)}_1,h^{(2)}_2)$ are assumed to be the Bernoulli distribution with Logistic probability function. There is no assumption of the probability function on $(h^{(2)}_1,h^{(2)}_2).$

As a generative model, how do we generate the samples of roots $(h^{(2)}_1,h^{(2)}_2)?$
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this tutorial](https://wiki.math.uwaterloo.ca/statwiki/index.php?title=the_Wake-Sleep_Algorithm_for_Unsupervised_Neural_Networks):

> To do this, for each unit of the top layer, the sigmoid function is simply applied to the additive constant in (1), as there are no subsequent layers providing influence.

This means only a bias is associated with the top random variables to parametrize the logistic function:

$p(h^{(2)}_1=1)=\frac{1}{1 + \exp(-b^{(2)}_1)}$ and $p(h^{(2)}_2=1)=\frac{1}{1 + \exp(-b^{(2)}_2)}$.